# Merge 2 SQL Server queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have to run every week a SQL Server query taking into accounts transactions starting from the latest Saturday at 00:01 until Saturday at 23:59 (Kuwait Time). The process takes into account thousands of rows and is there fore very heavy. I decided to do it in two steps, mostly because i could not manage to make it into a single one;)

I first have to offset the SQL Server date column of each transaction to Kuwait time.

I proceed in two steps since I use this script via PHP: I first define the latest Saturday date range (so for example, if the query is run on a Saturday it will calculate the range for the previous Saturday), and then use the variables for the second script.

Here here my first query getting the last Saturday :

```
SELECT
    (datetime, CASE 
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Sunday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Monday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Tuesday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -3, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Wednesday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -4, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) =  'Thursday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -5, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) =  'Friday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -6, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Saturday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -0, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
               END) at time zone 'Arab Standard Time' AS start_time,
 CONVERT(datetime, 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Sunday' THEN dateadd(day,0,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Monday' THEN dateadd(day,-1,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Tuesday' THEN dateadd(day,-2,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Wednesday' THEN dateadd(day,-3,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Thursday' THEN dateadd(day,-4,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Friday' THEN dateadd(day,-5,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Saturday' THEN dateadd(day,-6,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                     END) at time zone 'Arab Standard Time' as end_time
```

then I insert the variable $start_date and $end_date coming from above query in this other query to get the final result:

```
SELECT
    USERID,
    DEPOSIT,
    RMwin,
CASE
    WHEN DEPOSIT > 0 
        AND RMwin <= DEPOSIT 
        AND RMwin > 0 THEN
            RMWIN * 0.3 
            WHEN RMwin > DEPOSIT 
            AND DEPOSIT > 0 THEN
                DEPOSIT *.3 
                WHEN RMwin <= 0 THEN
                0 ELSE 0 
            END AS CB,
        CASE
                
                WHEN DEPOSIT + RMwin = 0 THEN
                0 ELSE 1 
            END AS check_,
            FORMAT ( min_lt, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' ) AS min_lt,
            format ( min_kuw, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' ) AS min_kuw,
            format ( max_lt, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' ) AS max_lt,
            format ( max_kuw, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' ) AS max_kuw,
            min_id,
            max_id 
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                UserID,
                SUM ( DEPOSIT ) AS DEPOSIT,
                SUM ( RMwin ) AS RMwin,
                MIN ( AccountTranID ) AS min_id,
                MAX ( AccountTranID ) AS max_id,
                MIN ( local_time ) AS min_lt,
                MIN ( kuwait_date ) AS min_kuw,
                MAX ( local_time ) AS max_lt,
                MAX ( kuwait_date ) AS max_kuw 
            FROM
                (
                SELECT
                    AccountTranID,
                    TranType,
                    UserID,
                    datetime,
                    datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AS local_time,
                    datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' AS kuwait_date,
                CASE
                        TranType 
                        WHEN 'GAME_B' THEN
                        - AmountReal 
                        WHEN 'GAME_W' THEN
                        - AmountReal 
                        WHEN 'REFUND' THEN
                        - AmountReal ELSE 0 
                    END AS RMwin,
                CASE
                        
                        WHEN TranType = 'DEPOSIT' THEN
                        AmountReal ELSE 0 
                    END AS DEPOSIT 
                FROM
                    admin_all.DataFeed 
                WHERE
                    datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' >= ( convert(datetime,'".$start_date."') AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' ) 
                    AND datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' < ( convert(datetime,'".$end_date."') AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' ) 
                ) trans 
            GROUP BY
                UserID 
            ) ok 
    ORDER BY
    CB DESC
```

This query is unfortunately extremely heavy for our server resources and I am trying to find a way to streamline it to reach the same result.

Would anyone have a solution to make that possible?

Comment: Your date range calculations do not work on Saturdays as start_time is *after* end_time. Last `WHEN` may need to be -7 instead of -0?

Answer (score 1):

Consider `DATEPART` for weekday numbers and apply arithmetic to retrieve last Saturday to last Sunday relative to current date. Below two expressions can replace the long `CASE` statements of first query:

```
DATEADD(DAY, -1*(DATEPART(DW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 
        CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)) AS LAST_SATURDAY
    
DATEADD(DAY, -1*(DATEPART(DW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1), 
        CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)) AS LAST_SUNDAY
```

From there, easily integrate to large query's `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE
 datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' >= 
  ( DATEADD(DAY, -1*(DATEPART(DW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 
            CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)) AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' ) 
AND datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' < 
  ( DATEADD(DAY, -1*(DATEPART(DW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1), 
            CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE))AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' )
...
```

---

**PHP**

And when run in PHP, consider [parameterization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1422451) where you can even calculate the dates in PHP (without a separate SQL query that only returns constants):

```php
$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("last Saturday"));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("last Sunday"));

$sql = "...
        WHERE 
            datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' >= ?
        AND datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' < ?
        ..."

$params = array($start_date , $end_date);

# sqlsrv API
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);

# odbc API
$stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
$success = odbc_execute($stmt, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query can be made simple like this (example with (test)output for august 2020):

```
declare @startdate datetime = '2020-08-01 00:00:00';
with testdates(d) as (
   select @startdate as d
   union all 
   select dateadd(day,1,d) from testdates where d<='2020-08-31')
select 
  d, 
  datepart(weekday,d),
  datename(weekday,d),
  dateadd(SECOND,1,dateadd(day,-(datepart(WEEKDAY,d)%7)-7,d)) start_time,
  dateadd(day,-(datepart(WEEKDAY,d)%7),d) end_time
from testdates;
```

output:

```
d                                                                  start_time              end_time
----------------------- ----------- ------------------------------ ----------------------- -----------------------
2020-08-01 00:00:00.000 7           Saturday                       2020-07-25 00:00:01.000 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000
2020-08-02 00:00:00.000 1           Sunday                         2020-07-25 00:00:01.000 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000
2020-08-03 00:00:00.000 2           Monday                         2020-07-25 00:00:01.000 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000
2020-08-04 00:00:00.000 3           Tuesday                        2020-07-25 00:00:01.000 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000
2020-08-05 00:00:00.000 4           Wednesday                      2020-07-25 00:00:01.000 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000
2020-08-06 00:00:00.000 5           Thursday                       2020-07-25 00:00:01.000 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000
2020-08-07 00:00:00.000 6           Friday                         2020-07-25 00:00:01.000 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000
2020-08-08 00:00:00.000 7           Saturday                       2020-08-01 00:00:01.000 2020-08-08 00:00:00.000
2020-08-09 00:00:00.000 1           Sunday                         2020-08-01 00:00:01.000 2020-08-08 00:00:00.000
2020-08-10 00:00:00.000 2           Monday                         2020-08-01 00:00:01.000 2020-08-08 00:00:00.000
2020-08-11 00:00:00.000 3           Tuesday                        2020-08-01 00:00:01.000 2020-08-08 00:00:00.000
2020-08-12 00:00:00.000 4           Wednesday                      2020-08-01 00:00:01.000 2020-08-08 00:00:00.000
2020-08-13 00:00:00.000 5           Thursday                       2020-08-01 00:00:01.000 2020-08-08 00:00:00.000
2020-08-14 00:00:00.000 6           Friday                         2020-08-01 00:00:01.000 2020-08-08 00:00:00.000
2020-08-15 00:00:00.000 7           Saturday                       2020-08-08 00:00:01.000 2020-08-15 00:00:00.000
2020-08-16 00:00:00.000 1           Sunday                         2020-08-08 00:00:01.000 2020-08-15 00:00:00.000
2020-08-17 00:00:00.000 2           Monday                         2020-08-08 00:00:01.000 2020-08-15 00:00:00.000
2020-08-18 00:00:00.000 3           Tuesday                        2020-08-08 00:00:01.000 2020-08-15 00:00:00.000
2020-08-19 00:00:00.000 4           Wednesday                      2020-08-08 00:00:01.000 2020-08-15 00:00:00.000
2020-08-20 00:00:00.000 5           Thursday                       2020-08-08 00:00:01.000 2020-08-15 00:00:00.000
2020-08-21 00:00:00.000 6           Friday                         2020-08-08 00:00:01.000 2020-08-15 00:00:00.000
2020-08-22 00:00:00.000 7           Saturday                       2020-08-15 00:00:01.000 2020-08-22 00:00:00.000
2020-08-23 00:00:00.000 1           Sunday                         2020-08-15 00:00:01.000 2020-08-22 00:00:00.000
2020-08-24 00:00:00.000 2           Monday                         2020-08-15 00:00:01.000 2020-08-22 00:00:00.000
2020-08-25 00:00:00.000 3           Tuesday                        2020-08-15 00:00:01.000 2020-08-22 00:00:00.000
2020-08-26 00:00:00.000 4           Wednesday                      2020-08-15 00:00:01.000 2020-08-22 00:00:00.000
2020-08-27 00:00:00.000 5           Thursday                       2020-08-15 00:00:01.000 2020-08-22 00:00:00.000
2020-08-28 00:00:00.000 6           Friday                         2020-08-15 00:00:01.000 2020-08-22 00:00:00.000
2020-08-29 00:00:00.000 7           Saturday                       2020-08-22 00:00:01.000 2020-08-29 00:00:00.000
2020-08-30 00:00:00.000 1           Sunday                         2020-08-22 00:00:01.000 2020-08-29 00:00:00.000
2020-08-31 00:00:00.000 2           Monday                         2020-08-22 00:00:01.000 2020-08-29 00:00:00.000
2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 3           Tuesday                        2020-08-22 00:00:01.000 2020-08-29 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With DateRange As
(SELECT
    (datetime, CASE 
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Sunday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Monday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Tuesday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -3, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Wednesday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -4, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) =  'Thursday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -5, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) =  'Friday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -6, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                  WHEN DATENAME(weekday, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Saturday' 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -0, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
               END) at time zone 'Arab Standard Time' AS start_time,
 CONVERT(datetime, 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Sunday' THEN dateadd(day,0,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Monday' THEN dateadd(day,-1,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Tuesday' THEN dateadd(day,-2,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Wednesday' THEN dateadd(day,-3,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Thursday' THEN dateadd(day,-4,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Friday' THEN dateadd(day,-5,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                            WHEN datename(weekday,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) = 'Saturday' THEN dateadd(day,-6,cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date))
                     END) at time zone 'Arab Standard Time' as end_time)

SELECT
    USERID,
    DEPOSIT,
    RMwin,
CASE
    WHEN DEPOSIT > 0 
        AND RMwin <= DEPOSIT 
        AND RMwin > 0 THEN
            RMWIN * 0.3 
            WHEN RMwin > DEPOSIT 
            AND DEPOSIT > 0 THEN
                DEPOSIT *.3 
                WHEN RMwin <= 0 THEN
                0 ELSE 0 
            END AS CB,
        CASE
                
                WHEN DEPOSIT + RMwin = 0 THEN
                0 ELSE 1 
            END AS check_,
            FORMAT ( min_lt, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' ) AS min_lt,
            format ( min_kuw, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' ) AS min_kuw,
            format ( max_lt, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' ) AS max_lt,
            format ( max_kuw, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' ) AS max_kuw,
            min_id,
            max_id 
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                UserID,
                SUM ( DEPOSIT ) AS DEPOSIT,
                SUM ( RMwin ) AS RMwin,
                MIN ( AccountTranID ) AS min_id,
                MAX ( AccountTranID ) AS max_id,
                MIN ( local_time ) AS min_lt,
                MIN ( kuwait_date ) AS min_kuw,
                MAX ( local_time ) AS max_lt,
                MAX ( kuwait_date ) AS max_kuw 
            FROM
                (
                SELECT
                    AccountTranID,
                    TranType,
                    UserID,
                    datetime,
                    datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AS local_time,
                    datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' AS kuwait_date,
                CASE
                        TranType 
                        WHEN 'GAME_B' THEN
                        - AmountReal 
                        WHEN 'GAME_W' THEN
                        - AmountReal 
                        WHEN 'REFUND' THEN
                        - AmountReal ELSE 0 
                    END AS RMwin,
                CASE
                        
                        WHEN TranType = 'DEPOSIT' THEN
                        AmountReal ELSE 0 
                    END AS DEPOSIT 
                FROM
                    admin_all.DataFeed 
                WHERE
                    datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' >= ( Select start_date from DateRange) AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' ) `enter code here`
                    AND datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Romance Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' < ( Select end_date from DateRange) AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time' ) 
                ) trans 
            GROUP BY
```

Comment: execute this query as a whole